# How to make permanent change to the column collation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Are there any configuration or option to make permanent change to the column collation so that I don't have to repeat `COLLATE` everywhere?

The following is my SQL query:

```
select
    y.[Key] FieldName,
    (select FieldName 
     from [dbo].GetFields(z.[Key]) 
     where FieldType = y.[Key] COLLATE Chinese_Taiwan_Stroke_CI_AS) COLLATE Chinese_Taiwan_Stroke_CI_AS
from
    FieldTableZ z
outer apply 
    FieldTableY y
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `option` but there is no way to only mention that collation once in that statement. You could add computed column(s) to your table to pre convert the data to that collation.

Comment: You repeat the option as many times as needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what are you trying to do here .. to change the collation of the entire server, the database or just for some columns? I'd try to answer all of them. A simple googling of "sql server change database collation" brings up these:

1. To change the server collation, there's the official documentation from Microsoft:

   - [Set or Change the Server Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation?view=sql-server-2017)

   And if you want a step-by-step guide, here it is:

   - [Changing SQL Server Collation After Installation - by Douglas Castilho](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation)
2. To change the database collation, for exmaple:

   `ALTER DATABASE CURRENT COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`
3. To change the collation of a table column:

   - [Change SQL Server Database Collation - Paris Polyzos' blog](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/12/07/change-sql-server-database)

   That is, you can alter the column collation with

   > `ALTER TABLE [<Table>] ALTER COLUMN [<Column>] <ColumnType> COLLATE <NewCollation>`

   It's not the case if you are using graph tables; the graph internal columns cannot be altered that way.

I'd nevertheless guess that none of these are acceptable for what the query looks like -- you made your `[Key]` column (which looks like a primary key) duplicate in the query and trying to rely on the side effect of collation .. BTW, try not to let people just do the googling work for you.